# Show fixed columns on page load and when user clicks on symbol show remaining columns in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I want to show only first two columns when user loads the page, and near table header an arrow mark or some symbol should be displayed and when user clicks that symbol the remaining columns should be shown.Could not find any samples online. Can we achieve this using html, javascript, jquery.Please find the sample in http://jsfiddle.net/TweNm/2338/.
My requirement is to show column A and B when user loads the page and an arrow near header, when user clicks the arrows the remaining columns should be displayed. Please suggest.

Below is the sample CSS code:

```
#table-wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
#table-scroll {
  height:150px;
  overflow:auto;  
  margin-top:20px;
}
#table-wrapper table {
  width:100%;

}
#table-wrapper table * {
  background:yellow;
  color:black;
}
#table-wrapper table thead th .text {
  position:absolute;   
  top:-20px;
  z-index:2;
  height:20px;
  width:35%;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's definitely doable!  You can hide all but the first two columns like this:

```
table.collapsed th:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)), 
table.collapsed td:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)) {
    visibility: hidden;   
}
```

And then just rig up some javascript to remove the collapes class from the table when you click the arrow.  Here is a very, very rough prototype based on the jsfiddle you provided:

http://jsfiddle.net/TweNm/2341/

Comment: Can we hide after viewing the columns C and D , i tried keeping &lt icon at column D and when user clicks on that C and D columnn should be hidden. Please find the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TweNm/2342/. @Casey Rule.